# Is it possible to search for a LaTeX command including its backslash?

Tags: support, search

I think a search for `\widthof` on any other command with backsalsh shows also results without considering `\`. Is it true? How can I make a search for a command and not for its name?

Comment: (Just to clarify) Do you mean searching on this (rather, the main) site?

Comment: I mean searching on tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 13):

The closest that I know of (or actually just found out about) is `code:"\widthof"`. This seems to search only for text that has been marked as code. As for its developmental status:

> It's not a secret, but it's not polished either...I was interrupted in the middle of implementing it and haven't re-visited it in a while. You're welcome to use it and we won't remove it. That being said, I don't feel it's 1.0 quality at this point, so haven't added it to documentation as I expect there are bugs I'll find with more testing locally. We're doing a *lot* behind the scenes right now, when that settles down I'll re-visit search (we have lots of ideas/code in the pipe there). – Nick Craver♦ [Sep 13 at 0:07](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146827/why-is-the-code-search-option-not-documented#comment421020_146827)

While I expected [`code:"\widthof"`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code:%22%5Cwidthof%22) to return pretty much the same results as [`widthof`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=widthof) (which shouldn't occur as non-code too often, right?), the former only returns 22 results, the latter 108. I haven't checked out where the difference comes from.

Comment: Thank you. It helps a little to restrict searches but I think it's a bit strict because it searches for complete words. If I search for `code:"\includegraphics[` only 4 results are shown because they include `\includegraphics[` followed by a ` ` (space) or return.

Comment: That sounds like a good point for a feature request on [metase], unless there already is one. A `*` wildcard might make sense here.